# Errors from simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm with several errors

```
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: /home/lineage/public_html/acp/xml/banners.xml:48: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: banner line 33 and list in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: &lt;/list&gt; in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]:        ^ in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: /home/lineage/public_html/acp/xml/banners.xml:48: parser error : Premature end of data in tag banner line 26 in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: &lt;/list&gt; in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]:        ^ in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: /home/lineage/public_html/acp/xml/banners.xml:48: parser error : Premature end of data in tag banner line 19 in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: &lt;/list&gt; in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]:        ^ in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: /home/lineage/public_html/acp/xml/banners.xml:48: parser error : Premature end of data in tag list line 2 in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]: &lt;/list&gt; in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  simplexml_load_file() [<a href='function.simplexml-load-file'>function.simplexml-load-file</a>]:        ^ in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 191
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 206
[23-Aug-2013 15:35:20 America/Sao_Paulo] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/lineage/public_html/acp/core.php on line 197
```

I took this system ever made but it does not know what it is happening!

line: 197 core.php

```
foreach ($this->getAll() as $banner) {
```

line: 191 core.php

```
$_xmlBanners = simplexml_load_file(PATH_XML."banners.xml");
```

Baners.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<list>
    <banner id="1">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/l2jbr.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='list_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
    <banner id="2">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/top100mmorpg.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
    <banner id="3">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/gamesitestop100.jpg</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        <banner id="4">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/arenatop100.png</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        <banner id="5">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/mmorpglist.jpg</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
        <banner id="6">
        <image>http://lineagefree.com/acp/images/top200.gif</image>
        <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/balsuoti-7907.php</link>
        <votes>
            <link>http://l2j.lt/topai/mokamas-7907.php</link>
            <regexp><div class='dlist_8' style="font-weight: bold">(.*)</div></regexp>
        </votes>
    </banner>
</list>
```

follows all data. if you need any more please ask me.
I'm desperate.
Sorry my english. was done with google!

Comment: *"I'm with several errors"* I'm sorry for you. But without more context it is pretty hard to help. Best I can do is tell you it seems like your XML is malformatted - **"premature end of data in tag"** does say a lot, you know. Can you post a sample of that XML?

Comment: The error messages imply that `banners.xml` contains `&lt;` and `&gt;` rather than `<` and `>`. These are the way that these characters are encoded in text nodes, but they're apparently around the tag names. What you posted in the question is what it looks like when you view it in a browser, since it decodes the entities. But SimpleXML requires that the XML file contain the decoded characters.

Comment: no have .. see post plz!

Comment: @Barmar Confusingly, it's the error message itself that is HTML formatted: note the `<a href...` for inline links to the online manual.

Answer (score 1):

The error message `Opening and ending tag mismatch: banner line 33 and list` is telling you that while parsing the XML file, the parser found an opening tag `<banner>`, and then some nested content, but when it was expecting the matching end tag `</banner>` it found a different end tag, `</list>`.

This generally happens when you have a tag opened somewhere that you never close, meaning the parser is still waiting for you to close it when it gets to the close of some outer block.

In this case, you can look through your XML and see that there are 6 opening `<banner>` tags, but only 3 closing `</banner>`, so something's clearly gone wrong.

In fact, you just seem to be missing the `</banner>` at the end of the banners with IDs 3, 4, and 5.